# DLL dependency of another DLL not found though loaded

Tags: c#, reflection

In a C# application I'm Loading 2 DLLs provided by user during runtime (not a pre-difined  reference) Let it be  A.dll, B.dll. 
A.dll is referencing B.dll, but they are supplied separately.
When I try to access a method from A.dll, with a parameter of type that is declared in B.dll, I get an:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'B, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.".

error, although both DLLs were loaded. Even calling `MethodInfo.GetParameters()` will throw the exception.

Tried to Load both DLLs with different methods:

```
Assembly.Load(<Path>) 
Assembly.LoadFile(<Path>) 
Assembly.LoadFrom(<Path>)
```

I set the reference in project A to B.dll as "Copy Local = false".

Any usage of types and method from A or B which does not involve the connection described above seems to work fine.

I made sure both assembly were loaded with 
    `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` 
(they both are).

I have to presume I don't have developer access to A.dll and B.dll projects (provided by users), but for testing purpose I can try to change stuff in them as well.

**Fusion log For A.dll:**

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/10/2019 @ 11:47:04 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs15_95cb26a8\JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.x64.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = A, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///<project fullpath>/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\u5r0nb10.kwf\k2mn3yzp.umi
LOG: AppName = AppTest
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///<project fullpath>/bin/Debug/A.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///<project fullpath>/bin/Debug/A/A.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///<project fullpath>/bin/Debug/A.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///<project fullpath>/bin/Debug/A/A.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Comment: Is `A` compiled against a different version of `B` than supplied?

Comment: Anyway [enable fusion logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) to see the actual error when loading assemblies fails.

Comment: A is compiled with the same version of B.

Comment: Fusion Log added as edit to original post

Answer (score 0):

You are missing are probably missing another dependency of B.dll it.
When you try to load a dll, Windows will try to look all dependency of it (other dlls). Unfortunately, the error you see will be:

> "The system can not find the specified"

All dependencies of B.dll should be also copied to the local directory.

Use [Dependency Walker .NET](https://github.com/isindicic/DependencyWalker.Net) to find the missing dependencies.

Comment: _"Any usage of types and method from A **or B** [...] seems to work fine."_

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. If that's correct, then working directly with B.dll should fail as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. I checked, everything is there.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is "there" I've got another possibility. Normally, this is obscure, but it can happen.

If B.dll depends on a higher version of a dll that your main program depends on, sometimes the lower version dll you loaded can't be made to work with the higher version B wants. In that case, you get this error.